# Java DataInputStream And FileWriter combination

Tags: java, io

I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    String path = "C:/Users/PRATYUSH/Documents/NetBeansProjects/File/NothingSpecial.txt";
    FileWriter file = new FileWriter(path);
    file.write("1.2356");
    System.out.println("Done check file now...");
    file.close();
    DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(path));
    double data = d.readFloat();
    System.out.println("Data from file = " + data);
    d.close();
}
```

I am getting `2.5348867449537238E-9` as my answer after execution. Why is it incorrect ?

Comment: Please format the code in your question properly by indenting with 4 spaces.

Comment: hey you are writing a String to your file and reading double

Answer (score 0):

You are writing character data and trying to read binary data. It doesn't make sense to use a `DataInputStream` unless the data was written with a `DataOutputStream`. In this case you are using a `FileWriter` so your solution starts with a `FileReader`, probably with a `Scanner` wrapped around it.

Answer (score 0):

To write using DataOuputStream:

```
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(
                           new FileOutputStream("file.txt"));

    out.writeDouble(10.8);
    out.writeChar('\t');
    out.writeInt(5);       
    out.writeChars(" \t ok \n");

out.close();
```

To read using DataInputStream:

```
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(
                          new FileInputStream("file.txt"));
try {
    while (true) {
        price = in.readDouble();
        in.readChar();       //throws out the tab
        unit = in.readInt();
        in.readChar();       //throws out the tab
        status= new StringBuffer(20);
        char lineSep = System.getProperty("line.separator").charAt(0);
        char chr;
        while ((chr = in.readChar() != lineSep) {
            desc.append(chr);
        }

        System.out.println("You've ordered " + unit +  " units of " 
                           + desc + " at $" + price);
        total = total + unit * price;
    }    
} catch (EOFException e) { }
System.out.println("For a TOTAL of: $" + total);
in.close();
```

To use FileWriter:

```
String name = "John Doe";
            int age = 44;
            double temp = 26.9;
            FileWriter fw;
            try {
                fw = new FileWriter(new File("mytextfile.txt"));
                fw.write(String.format("My name is %s.",name));
                fw.write(System.lineSeparator()); //new line
                fw.write(String.format("I am %d years old.",age));
                fw.write(System.lineSeparator()); //new line
                fw.write(String.format("Today's temperature is %.2f.",temp));
                fw.write(System.lineSeparator()); //new line
                fw.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```

To use FileReader:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("FileReaderDemo.java");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
String s;
while((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println(s); // or you can use the wrapper classes
}
fr.close();
```

Comment: `DataOutputStream` produces binary output, so it should not be saved in a file called .txt.

Comment: FileReader and FileWriter read and write Strings. While you have options for reading and writing with DataInputStream and DataOutputStream. So choose the option that suits your requirements instead of using a combinations among the 4.

Comment: @EJP... DataOutputStream lets you write primitives. It can very well read from a text file

Comment: Do read what I wrote. I didn't say anything about reading from a text file. I said that a file *name* containing .txt isn't *appropriate* to this case. NB  You are *writing binary* to this file.